# On the definition of Tor over differential graded algebras

Tags: differential-graded-algebras

Let $R$ be differential graded algebra, $M$ a left-module over $R$ and $N$ a right-module over $R$. Further, let $P^{*}$ be a proper projective resolution of $M$. I have seen that $Tor_R(N,M)$ is defined using the total differential of the double complex $N\otimes P^*$ (this is taken from McCleary), but why is that sensible?

In my mind, the thing that makes the most sense would be only to take the homology with respect to the external differential of the resolution $P^{*}$, so as to recover $N\otimes M$ in the degree zero part of $Tor_R(N,M)$.

Comment: If you mean Definition 7.5 of McCleary, then the discussion after the definition should convince you this is a reasonable definition.